# why the implicit intent in NotesList can't pass the intent-filter of my activity ? 

Tags: android, intentfilter

The sample NotesList(given by google,see it here: [Note Pad](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NoteEditor.html)) shows how to use intent filters.

In NotesList.java,this activity create a option menu and the menu add menu items based on available activities that accept an intent like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    // Create an Intent that describes the requirements to fulfill, to be included
    // in our menu. The offering app must include a category value of Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE.
    Intent intent = new Intent(null, dataUri);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);

    // Search and populate the menu with acceptable offering applications.
    menu.addIntentOptions(
         R.id.intent_group,  // Menu group to which new items will be added
         0,      // Unique item ID (none)
         0,      // Order for the items (none)
         this.getComponentName(),   // The current activity name
         null,   // Specific items to place first (none)
         intent, // Intent created above that describes our requirements
         0,      // Additional flags to control items (none)
         null);  // Array of MenuItems that correlate to specific items (none)

    return true;
}
```

The detail of this content is like this:

Action:null 
Type:null 
Data(uri):content://com.google.provider.NotePad/notes 
Category:android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE

I want my activity to be included in the menu,and the intent filter of my activity is like this:

```
＜intent-filter android:label="hello filter"＞
                ＜action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" /＞
                ＜category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/＞
                ＜data android:scheme="content" android:host="com.google.provider.NotePad"
                    android:path="notes" /＞
＜/intent-filter＞
```

it does not work.while if I change data into :
`< data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" / >`,it works.

It puzzled me because according to [intents-filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html):

> An Intent object that contains a URI
>   but no data type (and a type cannot be
>   inferred from the URI) passes the test
>   only if its URI matches a URI in the
>   filter and the filter likewise does
>   not specify a type. This will be the
>   case only for URIs like mailto: and
>   tel: that do not refer to actual data.

The intent in notesList only contains a URI(content://com.google.provider.NotePad/notes) and no data type,in My first intent filter,The uri matches the intent's uri,it should work but no,any one can explain why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You quoted the right paragraph, it says "This will be the case **only** for URIs like mailto: and tel: that **do not refer to actual data**.". But the the `content:` URI definitely refers to data, therefore you have to specify the type.

Comment: actually if i specify the type and uri at the same time,it won't work,instead ,if i only specify mimeType like this :<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" /> ,it will work,that's why I felt puzzled.

Comment: Actually with `content:`you don't need to specify the type from the docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html): `However, the MIME type can sometimes be inferred from the URI—particularly when the data is a content: URI, which indicates the data is located on the device and controlled by a ContentProvider, which makes the data MIME type visible to the system.`  in the case of a content: uri the type is supposed to be infered from the ContentProvider